# JupyterHub notebook server returning 500 error, pod stuck in "terminating" state

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, jupyterhub, amazon-eks

I have an AWS EKS cluster (kubernetes version 1.14) which runs JupyterHub application.

One of the users notebook servers is returning a 500 error

> 500 : Internal Server Error 
>   Redirect loop detected. Notebook has JupyterHub version unknown (likely < 0.8), but the hub expects 0.9.6. Try installing JupyterHub==0.9.6 in the user environment if you continue to have problems. 
>   You can try restarting your server from the homepage.

Only one user is experiencing this issue, others are not. When I do "kubectl get pod", this users pod shows that it is in state "terminating" (it appears to be stuck in this state).

Comment: Could you please add the logs (`kubectl logs <pod_name>`) and the description (`kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` of the pod in `terminating` status?

Comment: @willrof sorry I actually got it working again by forcefully deleting it -- in hindsight i would have preferred to diagnose the issue ... but oh well, at least it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it, but I can't say this is the right approach. (I would have preferred to diagnose the root cause)

1. First, I tried deleting the pod `kubectl delete pod <pod_name>` -- it did not work
2. Second, I tried force deleting the pod `kubectl delete pod <pod_name> --grace-period=0 --force` -- it worked, but it turns out this only deletes the handle, the pod resources are then orphaned on the cluster
3. I checked the node status `kubectl get node` and noticed one node was stuck in `NotReady` state. I recycled this node -- still did not work, the user notebook server was still stuck and returning 500 err
4. Finally, I simply deleted the user notebook server from the jupyter hub admin page. This fixed it....